# Django model, set default Form field of a model field

Tags: django, model, field

Is it possible to add, say, a charfield to a model and overriding the default formfield without creating a subclass of CharField?

Pseudo code:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    reg_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        default_form_field=localflavor.se.fields.reg_number_field
    )
```